# Closing question when asking an advice

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing, closed-questions

So, recently I asked on the main Mathematics site about interesting subjects for my thesis. And it was closed as opinion-based.
Btw this is my question:
[My question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3778364/664855)

Then, I tried to looking for similar question and I found this: [interesting-first-order-odes-in-applied-science](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/653519).

So what's the problem that made my question is closed? I mean, even if someone gives me an idea for my thesis, it doesn't mean my thesis 100% talking about his idea right? And it's not plagiarism. And it could be that I did not choose any of their suggestions. Again, so what's the problem? Is this kind of question really a bad idea to ask here?

Comment: You are literally asking for opinions. What is the most interesting something is a "bad subjective" question. Not to mention that this site is not meant for academic advice (if it comes out organically, that's great, but it's not the topic of questions).

Comment: @AsafKaragila so what about the second question that i have mentioned? It's asking for opinion too. They don't mind when I ask for suggestions for the best books to use ... That can also mean "there are bad books"

Comment: The second question I see is an open ended "please give me some suggestions", which (again) is not on topic in this website. You can easily identify the problem with the second paragraph: you want to *discuss*. But this is not a *forum* for discussions, this is a Q&A website. The goal is to ask as concrete questions as possible that have as concrete answers as possible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila actually someone suggested to me to ask here about my question. And to be honest i've edited my question. I mentioned that i'm working on my thesis. That's all.

Comment: Personally I think the second question you linked are not that opinion-based: They are asking specifically examples that are suitable for use in teaching a first course in ODE, and that is quite an objective criterion since the materials in such a course are standard.

Comment: @ArcticChar: This *could* be a borderline "good subjective" question. But currently the phrasing of the question is easily mistakable for asking for open-ended advice and subjective opinions.

Comment: Yes the phrasing is not clear enough. Would fix that after this meta post is done and dusted. @AsafKaragila

Comment: @ArcticChar: That's natural. English is not my native language. But, i expected some expert to edit the question to help or make it clear instead of closing. There are a lot of people can't express what This makes some people especially for me really disappointed with this site. Many people can't express what they thought.  That's why they are asking.

Comment: In this situation I think it is very hard for others to help. Only you can tell us what is "most interesting", "exciting", "easy to calculate and not really complicated"..... These are very subjective. @user516076

Comment: Ok thanks anyway for the advice.